# Openhab2 stops processing events from ZWave ZW096 Smart Switch 6

Tags: events, openhab, z-wave

My Openhab 2 installation starts logging the following message:

```
Already processed another send data request for this callback Id, ignoring.
```

and I am not able to see any more events logged on my mysql database.

I have Openhab2 with a Z-Wave Node 2: ZW096 Smart Switch 6 and set the persistence with mysql database.
I have all the devices online (the zwave Serial Controller attached on /dev/ttyACM0 port, a zwave bulb online and obviously the Zwave smart switch) and I set on the ZWave Smart Switch a polling period of 15 seconds (I need to react to suddenly watts changes on the zwave switch so I cannot set a slower frequency).
Everything worked well until suddenly the openhab2 log started logging the warning:

```
2018-02-16 11:16:07.037 [WARN ] [l.serialmessage.SendDataMessageClass] - 
NODE 2: Already processed another send data request for this callback Id,
ignoring.
```

and the events on mysql database are not written anymore.

Any ideas?

I've tried to reset the switch, switch off and on but the only solution by now is to restart openhab.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I eventually found that there was some problem between the smart switch, the zwave gateway usb key and OpenHab2. I did a reset to all the zwave devices and rebound them to the gateway, added a refresh job that every 2 seconds requests the REFRESH to the smart switch and everything started working.
Sometimes the plug still doesn't refreshes the data and I have to reset it.